# Problem accessing a structure from a signal handler

Tags: c

I want to start of this post by saying that I'm pretty sure the problem is not with my linked list implementation because I tested it separately from the signal handler and the `search` function worked. I made a program with execute multiple program which are passed as argument, the programs can be for example a shell script which contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
kill $$
```

What I want is to create a linked list containing all the pid of the executed program as key, and as value an index, for example;

```
12332 = 1
12333 = 2
12333 = 3
```

Then I want my signal handler to make a `lookup` in the linked list to find the corresponding `pid`, then print the index and the exit status in the order they exited like this :

```
The process number 2 exited with signal 15
The process number 1 exited with signal 0
The process number 3 exited with signal 1
```

Here is what I made so for, I put a `sleep(200)` at the end of my program because otherwise it goes in an infinite loop. Right now the output is `The process number 0 exited with signal 15`, while it should be `The process number 1 exited with signal 15` instead, since `1` is the value associated with the process that exited with the signal 15. I think it's because my signal handler doesn't have proper access to the `linkedList`, so `search` return 0. How can I solve this?

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio_ext.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

/* Link list node */
struct Node
{
    int key;
    int pid;
    struct Node* next;
};
  
/* Given a reference (pointer to pointer) to the head
  of a list and an int, push a new node on the front
  of the list. */
void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_key, int new_pid)
{
    /* allocate node */
    struct Node* new_node =
            (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  
    /* put in the key  */
    new_node->key  = new_key;
    new_node->pid = new_pid;
    /* link the old list off the new node */
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
  
    /* move the head to point to the new node */
    (*head_ref)    = new_node;
}
  
/* Checks whether the value x is present in linked list */
int search(struct Node* head, int x)
{
    // Base case
    if (head == NULL)
        return false;
      
    // If key is present in current node, return the key
    if (head->pid == x)
        return head->key;
  
    // Recur for remaining list
    return search(head->next, x);
}
  
struct Node* linkedList = NULL;

void handler(int sig)
{

  
  pid_t pid;
  int status;
  pid = wait(&status);
  int i = search(linkedList, pid);
  if (pid != -1 )
  {

    
    if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
      printf("The process number %d exited with signal %d\n", i,  WEXITSTATUS(status));
  }
    else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
      printf("The process number %d exited with signal %d\n", i , WTERMSIG(status));
    } else
       printf("Error with the waiting process\n");
  }
}
/* Driver program to test count function*/
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  signal(SIGCHLD, handler);

     // create one exec by prog
  for (int j = 0; j < argc; j++)
  {
    
 
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
    {
      char *new_args[4];
      new_args[0] = "sh";
      new_args[1] = "-c";
      new_args[2] = argv[j];
      new_args[3] = NULL;
      int temp = getpid();
      push(&linkedList, j+1, temp);

      execv("/bin/bash", new_args);
  }
  }
    sleep(200);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Surely each child has its own copy of the linked list, and only children are pushing something to it. While `SIGCHILD` is only received by parent, who has it empty.

Comment: You are totally right I didn't think about this simple problem.

Comment: Please fix your `search` function so that it is not recursive. It doesn't need to be, so don't waste your stack.

Comment: You can't write arbitrary C code in signal handlers. Your code is full of Undefined Behavior.